# Rotating Observers in Kerr Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, vector-fields, kerr-metric

I am learning about the Kerr metric and I am using the book *Gravitation - Foundations and Frontiers by T. Padmanabhan*.

While discussing a 'static limit' he considers an observer rotating with an angular velocity given by $\Omega = \frac{d \phi}{dt} = \frac{u^{\phi}}{u^t}$. He now makes the assertion that the four velocity of the observer $u$ can be given by

$\tag1 u = u^t(\partial_t + \Omega \partial_{}\phi) $

since it is 'obvious' that the direction of the four velocity of such an observer must be along the $\xi_t + \Omega \xi_{\phi} = \partial_t + \Omega \partial_{}\phi$.

However, this does not seem obvious to me and in fact, I am not able to visualize the directions given by these Killing vectors to begin with. Hence, my questions are:

1. Why is this four velocity right?
2. How can I begin to understand the physical directions of Killing vectors better, without knowing the integral curves that they generate?